# One word for someone who always does what he loves

Tags: single-word-requests, epithet-requests

I am looking for one word to describe someone who always does what he loves.

*Loving* means enjoying something very much, *free-spirited* means not restrained by convention. Is there a hybrid word?

I mean a word that describes someone who is independent and always does what he loves. Please also try to not make the word too esoteric. Also, the word needs to be positive.

How will it be used?

I am submitting an application for college, and they require me to supply a word to describe myself. I have always done what I love. So, I require a word to describe someone who loves what they want. There is no sentence, in particular, just a prompt asking me to describe myself in one word.

Comment: "Extraordinarily lucky" is the term I would use.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Questions on **choosing an ideal word or phrase** must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: Sounds like a *hedonist,* to me. That may not be entirely positive, depending on your point of view.

Comment: @AndrewLeach IMO someone might be a hedonist but not always be "doing what they love". Maybe they don't have the opportunity, or maybe they don't think it is wise. I think that hedonism is more about maximising pleasure and minimizing pain, and that doesn't have to mean that you think that *always* loving what you're doing is practical, wise, or expedient. So if you hate exercise but do it anyway because of the health benefits ("long-term pleasure"), you're not *always doing what you love*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollyanna isn't quite it, but may convey the general concept (ie, loves what he does, which would imply does what he loves, but has a different meaning).

Comment: Hard to fit into one word, but this sounds like a combination of ***single*** and ***retired***.    :-)    ⁠

Comment: Is this okay or any other explanation is required?

Answer (score 2):

How about *hedonist*?

OD:

[*hedonist*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hedonist): a person who believes that the pursuit of pleasure is the most important thing in life; a pleasure-seeker

I consider *hedonist* a neutral word, simply a statement of fact about certain persons, no value judgment implied.

Comment: I feel that "pleasure" as in "pleasure-seeker" has a more narrow sense than "doing what one loves", since "what one loves" can be a large range of things and the details of what "love" means to a person can be subtle and complicated. In contrast, "pleasure" is much more associated with sensory pleasure and indulgence. So e.g. I might *love* raising my kids even though there might be a lot of pain associated with it; I might *love* doing it despite the lack of pleasure, or presence of pain.

Comment: Although the author's sense of "love" as meaning "enjoying something very much" might be more narrow than the one I'm using. +1 in any case.

Comment: Pursuit of pleasure seems to be a little negative. Is there something more positive? @Guildenstern is right, it seems to be narrow. I searched for meaning of love on internet and this one seems to be okay. A general term will be better.

Comment: Just for clarification "this one" in above comment means my definition of love not the term. Don't feel yourself restricted by the definition

Comment: @Guildenstern sense of love is best to go with. I kind of meant that definition but was not able to write in words. Sorry for the trouble and replying late. My internet went out. :(

Answer (score 0):

A word that may be in the same vein as *hedonist* is ***Epicurean***:

> [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/epicurean):
>
>   devoted to sensual pleasures, esp food and drink; hedonistic
>
> [English Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/epicurean):
>
> - A disciple or student of the Greek philosopher Epicurus.
>
>   A person devoted to sensual enjoyment,
>     especially that derived from fine food and drink.
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epicurean):
>
>   of or relating to Epicurus or Epicureanism

Apparently it should be capitalized
when it’s referring specifically to Epicurus,
and may be lower case when referring to the lifestyle.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicureanism) says,

> The philosophy originated by Epicurus flourished for seven centuries. 
>   It propounded an ethic
>   of individual pleasure as the sole or chief good in life. 
>   Hence, Epicurus advocated living in such a way
>   as to derive the greatest amount of pleasure possible during one’s lifetime,
>   yet doing so moderately
>   in order to avoid the suffering incurred by overindulgence in such pleasure. 
>   The emphasis was placed on pleasures of the mind
>   rather than on physical pleasures. 
>   Therefore, according to Epicurus,
>   with whom a person eats is of greater importance than what is eaten. …

… which seems to differ slightly from the dictionary definitions.

Comment: I think admission officers will only look at dictionary definition rather than Wikipedia. I am submitting an application for colleges, and they require me to supply a word to describe me. Epicurean will give them a wrong image.

Comment: … which is an excellent illustration of why word requests should include information on how the word will be used.

Comment: Follow-up question: should it be “they require me to supply a word to describe me” or “they require me to supply a word to describe **myself**”?

Comment: It's myself. I'm sorry.